# Button below listView: android

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview

I have a listFragment that has a custom layout, defined by the following XML. 
however, the button is completely hidden by the list fragment. 
What's wrong in the XML ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
           />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/android:list"
     android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried changing the layout_height of the listview from `match_parent` to `0dp` but then the `listView` becomes hidden and only the button is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // set your button at the bottom
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1" // place listview above button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
    </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can add a view as a footer to the lsitview. As an alternative you can add button as a footer to listview.

Answer (score -3):

Your task will be accomplished by this linear layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no this is wrong listview will take the whole space. coz your lsitview has `match_parent` for both height and width

Comment: edit your answer what you have posted won't work as op expects

Comment: won't work if the lsitview content is more also you have not mentioned the orientation